# Get service operations list from soapui project file

Tags: soapui

I am using SOAPUI 4.5 free version.

I would like to  programmatically get the  list of service operations from the SOAPUI project using GrovyScript.

Can you please guide me on this .

Answer (score 1):

Here it is

```
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.*;

String projectFile ="PATHTO/GoogleSearch-soapui-project.xml";
WsdlProject project = new WsdlProject (projectFile);

List operationList = project.getInterfaceAt(0).getAllOperations();

int length = operationList.size();
String name;

for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
    name = operationList.get(i).getName();
    log.info name;
}
```

It is working.